# Lua : 'until' expected (to close 'repeat' at line 7) near 'elseif'

Tags: lua, udp

I’m trying to put together some Lua code that will send a command and then capture all the broken up responses that come back from a udp device.

Here is my current code

```
local udp = socket.udp()
udp:settimeout(0)
udp:setpeername("172.16.0.23", 65432)
local cmd = "$RS232 test message\r"
udp:send(cmd)

repeat
    local data, msg = udp:receive()
    if data then 
        print("received:", data)
        end
    elseif msg ~= 'timeout' then 
        error("Network error: "..tostring(msg))
    end
until not data
```

But it keeps giving me the following error..

```
Code error: Line 12: 'until' expected (to close 'repeat' at line 7) near 'elseif'
```

Any ideas what I’m missing ?

A quick bit of background on the udp (serial rs232) device I’m connecting to, the data is sent as a lot of two or threee byte packets. This is because of the RS232 data rate and the device uses interupts to process the data. Basically the udp device receives a few bytes, interrupt fires, it processes those then receives a few more interrupt fires again, etc etc.

So the above repeat loop is to ensure I have captured everything it’s got for me?

Answer (score 3):

Your if statement is ended prematurely.

```
 if data then 
        print("received:", data)
        end                      -- remove this end!
    elseif msg ~= 'timeout' then 
        error("Network error: "..tostring(msg))
    end
```

That repeat statement doesn't make too much sense imho. Why don't you use a timeout instead?

If you removed that `end` you will receive once with timeout 0. As your peer never had a chance to respond data will be nil and your repeat loop will terminate.

Maybe give the documentation another read.

Also I don't understand how you relate udp to rs232. That's two completely different things.

Comment: Thanks @piglet, the udp element is needed to connect to the serial/rs232 that is actually sending/receiving the commands. (There is sadly no manual for this, jUst some limited tech support)  My idea for the repeat was to keep checking if there was something there .  Can I just confirm your reply, it sounds like while removing the `end` will address the error, i should probably just remove that repeat part altogether and just extend the udp time out ? `udp:settimeout(5)` ?

Comment: FYI - I had started with something very basic `local ip, port = "172.16.0.23", 65432
local socket = require("socket")
local udp = assert(socket.udp())
assert(udp:sendto("$RS232 test", ip, port))
print(assert(udp:receive()))` but it didn’t give anything back and would just get stuck, lock up so I added the time out .. After that the original post grew from there as I was not (and I’m still not) getting any responses come back....